# Hypothesis testing with repeated measures per subject per condition + multiple conditions with repeated measures + hypothesis of previous hypotheses

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I am a statistical noobie and I will need to do some testing of the hypotheses of child patients but I am not sure which tests should be performed and how.

I have measures of different metrics per each child on day 1 at a few particular hours and then other measures on the second day of the same patients at the same hours but with different conditions.

Also, some measures have multiple values as there has been a small workout at each hour and those values are measured before and after for some metrics.

So I have ended up with the data like this per each child:
[image: Format of the data]

My hypotheses are (ordered from easiest to perform to hardest in my opinion):

1. Children fall asleep sooner with white noise in the background.
2. Children have lower heart rates when white noise is played in the background.
3. Children have better vital functions when white noise is being played in the background (This one is a result of an HR, Number of breaths, and Saturation at once)

Thank you very much for any suggestions and help to perform these tests :)

I am pretty lost due to having those multiple measures as I can't find many articles that would work with data like this :/